# Commmon menu for multiple aspx pages

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've been working on a project and I noticed I reuse the same menu over and over again and it got to a point where, if I needed to change something I would need to change 20+ pages too because of it being a menu.

My question is, is it possible to have a single `aspx` file with the working menu on it, and have the other pages call it? So far I've tried

```
<?php include('Menu.aspx') ?> 

<iframe id="myIframe" src="Menu.aspx" height="100%" width="100%"></iframe>
```

The later (iframe) showed something but I was unable to resize it and the links didn't work either. The `php` one didn't show anything. Any help would be appreciated, thank you very much.

Comment: Why are you using php in an aspx file??? Please confirm what language and framework you are actually using, eg `c# asp.net webforms` without that info none of the answers here are any use

Comment: I am using `c# asp.net webforms`. From the information that I have seen, everyone said that you can use `php` in aspx files, so I gave it a try.

Comment: For WebForms create a user control that renders the menu, and then use that control in each page with the menu,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following approaches to solve this:

- Master Pages allow to have a common layout that is applied to several aspx pages. The master page defines a layout and provides some content placeholders that are filled in by the pages that reference the master page. Your example of a menu fits good; the menu would be placed on the master page. See this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wtxbf3hh.aspx) for details.
- Another way to share layouts are ASP.NET UserControls. These are created as ascx files and can be reused in several aspx pages. See this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb3w5b53.aspx) for details.

Comment: Thank you very much. I decided to use a Master Page, it was confusing at first, but it worked out great :)

Answer (score 1):

The best option for you is to create an [User Control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y6wb1a0e.aspx), and use it in all your pages.

An user control is similar to a server control (e.g. asp textbox, update panel etc.), but custom made by the developer to suit his specific needs.

If the menu is more like the common layout/theme of all your pages you can use a [Master Page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wtxbf3hh.aspx) instead.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make yourself familiar with master pages. See this as a beginner tutorial: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/333650/Beginner-s-Tutorial-on-Master-Pages-in-ASP-NET

Answer (score 0):

There are two option to reuse menu in asp.net page.

1. Master Page
2. User Control

using sitemap and add into master page.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa581781.aspx

http://webproject.scottgu.com/CSharp/MasterPages/MasterPages.aspx

Hope this will help you.
thanks